# TypeError: Cannot read property '$fetch' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

i am using angular-js,angular-restmod and ui-router to build an app that has the following restmod models

```
    app.factory('Event', function(restmod) {
       return restmod.model('v1/events').mix(
         {
           user: {belongsTo: 'User', key: 'user_id'}
         }
       );
    });

    app.factory('User', function(restmod) {
      return restmod.model('v1/users');
    });
```

i have a controller that lists the events present in the database

```
    app.controller('EventsController', function($scope,Event,User) {

       $scope.eventsList = [];

       var events = Event.$search();
       for (event in events) {
        event.user.$fetch();
       }
       $scope.eventsList = events;
    })
```

i am getting an error - TypeError: Cannot read property '$fetch' of undefined
for the line 'e.user.$fetch();'

i cannot figure out what is wrong in the code. can anybody help please.

Comment: are you sure your "event" object has a property called user? That error is indicating that property doesn't exist. Check if event.user contains what you are expecting. I would check the Event.$search method to ensure events variable is being correctly populated

Comment: events variable is not populated even though i am getting a response from the server. i checked the network tab in chromes developer tools and the server responded with

Comment: 0: {id: "1", name: "test", user_id: "1", date: "2015-04-16", description: "testing", active: "0",…}
1: {id: "2", name: "test2", user_id: "2", date: "2015-04-08", description: "testing 2", active: "1",…}

Comment: I'm not really familiarized with restmod, but wouln't you need to make a events.$refresh() in order to retrieve the info in your variable?